# Implementing map() and each() over std::tuple<...> - with index passed to functor as template parameter

Tags: c++, tuples, c++14, template-meta-programming, typename

After a few years of web development, I'm working in C++ (14) again and decided to have some "dynamically typed functional fun" with template metaprogramming.

I have implemented `map` and `each` over tuples:

```
template <typename Tuple, typename Func, size_t... index>
void tuple_each_internal(Tuple const & tuple, Func func, index_sequence<index...>)
{
    auto res = {
        (func(get<index>(tuple)), nullptr)...
    };
}

template <typename Tuple, typename Func, typename Indices = make_index_sequence<tuple_size<Tuple>::value>>
void tuple_each(Tuple const & tuple, Func func)
{
    tuple_each_internal(tuple, func, Indices());
}

struct demo_functor_each {

    /* Case #1: "Each" callback */
    template <typename T>
    void operator ()(T&& t) { ; }

    /* Case #2: "Each with index as run-time parameter" callback */
    //template <typename T>
    //void operator ()(const size_t index, T&& t) { ; }

    /* Case #3: "Each with index as compile-time parameter" callback */
    //template <typename T, size_t index>
    //void operator ()(T&& t) { ; }

};

void Example_Usage()
{
    tuple<int, bool, string> t;
    tuple_each(t, demo_functor_each());
}
```

And a similar implementation of `map`.

- Case #1 passes syntax check (I haven't tried running it yet).
- Case #2 also passes syntax check, with `tuple_each_internal` modified to pass the index as a function parameter: `func(index, get<index>(tuple))`.
- Case #3 is superior to case #2 in that the value of `index` can be passed to other templates at compile time (e.g. `get<index>(tuple)`), which is not possible in case #2.

I have been unable to implement case #3.

Given the callback signature:

```
template <typename T, size_t index>
void operator ()(T&& t) { ; }
```

I tried this as `tuple_each_internal`:

```
auto res = {
    (func<typename tuple_element<index, Tuple>::type, index>(get<index>(tuple)), nullptr)...
};
```

## Clang++ 3.6.1 output:

```
$ clang++ -std=c++14 tuple_iteration.h

error: expected '(' for function-style cast or type construction

auto res = { (func<typename tuple_element<index, Tuple>::type, index>(get<index>(tuple)), nullptr)... };
                   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^
```

## g++ 5.1.0 output:

```
$ g++ -std=c++14 tuple_iteration.h

error: expected ‘(’ before ‘,’ token

auto res = { (func<typename tuple_element<index, Tuple>::type, index>(get<index>(tuple)), nullptr)... };
                                                             ^
```

Comment: With a working `each`, implementing `map` was trivial — but if anyone needs help with it, drop me a message.

Comment: I was able to repro the functionality in your example with fold expressions in C++17. But, using C++14, I don't understand the syntax here: 

auto res = {
        (func(get<index>(tuple)), nullptr)...
    }; 

I get that it's expanding the pack, but how? What's the role of "nullptr"?
 Would you mind explaining it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @bluescorpion: the `, nullptr`discards the result (if any) of the callback, allowing us to call multiple functions, possibly with different or no return types, in a single expression.  The type of each expanded term is now nullptr_t.  We could have used an int or something else, but then it might be harder to read due to people thinking there was actually some meaning in the value ;)

Comment: This syntax construction is what I don't get: auto res /*I get it*/ = {(<function_call>/*I get it*/, nullptr)...}. The (,) pair is one thing that baffles me, then the fact that there's no comma before ellipsis...

Comment: @bluescorpion The , pair is just the normal , operator which should almost never ever be used in a good program.  The parenthesized expression is expanded into a comma-separated list due to parameter pack expansion via the ... operator.

Comment: @bluescorpion At least that's how I think it works now but I haven't done much C++ lately.

Comment: I assumed the ellipsis operator would expand the expression before it into (what I think is) an initializer_list (between {}). If so, then the expansion would look like: {(expr1, nullptr) /* Ooops: no comma here? */ (expr2, nullptr) ... (expr_n, nullptr)}, which shouldn't compile because there's no comma between the (,) pairs. I'm obviously misinterpreting the way this is expanded... Thank you.

Comment: The ... pack expansion effectively inserts the commas, think about the typical parameter forwarding example: `template <typename... Args> RetT proxy(Args&&... args) { return target(std::forward<Args>(args)...); }`.  No commas there.

Comment: I see. So, effectively after expansion this should look like this:
auto res = {(<expr1>, nullptr), (<expr2>, nullptr),...,(<expr_n>, nullptr)}. Right? Thanks.

Comment: @bluescorpion Yep.  That's it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be:

```
auto res = {
    (func.template operator()<const typename tuple_element<index, Tuple>::type&, index>(get<index>(tuple)),
     nullptr)...
};
```

[Live Demo](https://ideone.com/tprFcF).

Simpler with

```
/* Case #4: "Each with index as compile-time parameter" callback */
template <size_t index, typename T>
void operator ()(T&& t);
```

where code becomes:

```
auto res = {
    (func.template operator()<index>(get<index>(tuple)),
     nullptr)...
};
```

[Live Demo](https://ideone.com/aylOql)

or even

```
template <size_t N, typename T>
void operator ()(std::integral_constant<std::size_t, N>, T&& t);
```

which results in

```
auto res = {
    (func(std::integral_constant<std::size_t, index>{}, get<index>(tuple)),
     nullptr)...
};
```

[Live Demo](https://ideone.com/ZTiDqb)

Comment: Ahhh noob error on my part with `template` resolution...  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For what is worth, here's an example of doing something similar in C++17, using fold expressions on the comma operator:

```
//Example of creating a pack of vectors from a pack of template args, one vector for each type ("rotating" the pack 90 deg)


#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <tuple>
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>
#include <numeric>
#include <iterator>

#include <utility>//index_sequence
//
//g++ -std=c++1z rotate_pack.cpp -o rotate_pack.exe
//
//
template<typename ...Ts>
struct SOA_State
{

  explicit SOA_State(size_t n):tuple_vecs_(std::vector<Ts>(n, Ts())...)//ok
  {
  }

  //using fold expresions for "," (comma) operator; requires c++17
  //
  template<typename ...Fs,                                         //pack of functor types
       std::size_t ...Is>                                      //pack of tuple indices to fold over
  void transform_pack(const std::tuple<Fs...>& fctr_pack,          //pack of fctrs
              std::tuple<std::vector<Ts>...>& result_pack, //pack of result vectors
              std::index_sequence<Is...>)
  {
    (std::transform(std::begin(std::get<Is>(tuple_vecs_)),std::end(std::get<Is>(tuple_vecs_)),
            std::begin(std::get<Is>(result_pack)),//std::back_inserter?
            std::get<Is>(fctr_pack)), ...);
  }

  //using fold expresions for "," (comma) operator; requires c++17
  //
  template<typename ...Fs,                                         //pack of functor types
       std::size_t ...Is>                                      //pack of tuple indices to fold over
  static
  void foreach_pack(const std::tuple<Fs...>& fctr_pack,            //pack of fctrs
            std::tuple<std::vector<Ts>...>& source_pack,   //pack of result vectors
            std::index_sequence<Is...>)
  {
    (std::for_each(std::begin(std::get<Is>(source_pack)),std::end(std::get<Is>(source_pack)),
           std::get<Is>(fctr_pack)), ...);
  }

private:
  std::tuple<std::vector<Ts>...> tuple_vecs_;//ok
};

int main(void)
{
  size_t n_states = 10;
  SOA_State<int, double, std::string> soa(n_states);

  auto fctr_tuple = std::make_tuple([](const int& v){return v+1;}, [](const double& v){return 2.0*(v+.13);}, [](const std::string& s){return std::string("hello");});
  auto res_tuple = std::make_tuple(std::vector<int>(n_states,0), std::vector<double>(n_states,0.), std::vector<std::string>(n_states,std::string()));
  std::index_sequence_for<int, double, std::string> is;

  //apply transform on pack with results in another pack:
  //
  soa.transform_pack(fctr_tuple, res_tuple, is);

  auto printer_tuple = std::make_tuple([](const int& v){std::cout<<"i:"<<v<<"\n";}, [](const double& v){std::cout<<"d:"<<v<<"\n";}, [](const std::string& s){std::cout<<"s:"<<s<<"\n";});

  //print the results pack:
  //
  SOA_State<int, double, std::string>::foreach_pack(printer_tuple, res_tuple, is);
  std::cout<<"\n";

  std::cout<<"Done!"<<std::endl;
};
```